# How to print Hello!World

Tags: bash

More broadly, how to echo
! in bash without space in between

```
karthik@cosmic:~$ echo "Hello!World"
bash: !World: event not found
karthik@cosmic:~$ echo "Hello\!World"
Hello\!World
karthik@cosmic:~$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to someone, the solution is simple.

Remove those double quotes and escape the `!`:

```
echo Hello\!World
```

or with bash 4.3 or newer, use double quotes but make sure the `!` is immediately followed by the closing quote:

```
echo "Hello!""World"
```

From [the release notes in bash 4.3](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-4.3#n43):

> l.  The history expansion character (!) does not cause history expansion when followed by the closing quote in a double-quoted string.

Best is to use single quotes inside which all characters lose their special meaning¹.

```
echo 'Hello!World'
```

Or disable csh-style history expansion altogether with:

```
histchars=
```

Or:

```
set +o histexpand
```

Or:

```
set +H
```

Note that history expansion is only enabled by default when bash is interactive, not in scripts.

---

<sup>As long as the deprecated `` `...` `` form of command substitution is not also used, as inside it, `\` retains a special meaning even inside single quotes.</sup>

Comment: @terdon and @karthik `Hello World!`  is not the same as `Hello!World` when it comes to csh-style history expansion interference.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it was someone else who edited and made the answer look like that. I did rollback. check now

Comment: `echo Hello!World` doesn't work. `!` is even more a problem outside of `"..."` than inside though outside, you can escape it with backslash.

Comment: `echo "Hello""!""World"` doesn't work either in older versions of `bash`. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Both works here. why cant we use 'newer' versions of bash?

Comment: Oh wow, sorry @StéphaneChazelas and Karthik, I had misread the question as being about `Hello World!` and not `Hello!World` which is indeed a different issue. Karthik, I escaped the `!` in your unquoted example since that won't work otherwise. And there is no reason we can't use newer versions, it's just that not everyone has newer versions so we like to point out limitations of our answers.

Comment: @terdon Thanks. Much appreciated